# Angular: exporting service-results to the component - best style?

Tags: angular

Lets say I have a service and I need its results in my component.

```
<p>{{ foo.getit () }}</p>
...

constructor (private foo : MyFooService)
{
}
```

That is an error if building the app for production (ng build --prod) because of accessibility.

Is it better style to declare foo public OR wrap it with a public method (as I do below)?

```
<p>{{ getFoo ().getit () }}</p>
...

constructor (private foo : MyFooService)
{
}

getFoo ()
{
  return this.foo;
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think it's depend on your purpose, but totally I prefer your second way.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is.

you should put your function result in a component variable this way angular change detection doesn't spam `foo.getit` with handed of calls
or fall in an infinite change detection loop

```
<p>{{ getFooTit() }}</p>
...

constructor (private foo: MyFooService){}
fooTitResult
getFooTit()
{
  if(!this.fooTitResult){
      this.fooTitResult = this.foo.getit();
  }
  return this.fooTitResult;
}
```